# Ultra-low contrast submit button in flagging dialog

Tags: bug, design

The flagging dialog here on meta looks like this:

[image]

Note that the button is hard to notice in the first place (worse before selecting an option), and the text is almost illegible.

Comment: Applies to other buttons, e.g. "Add Comment" on the main site.